# How do I fix IE broken corners when using border radius (ridge)

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am styling a div with the following:

```
border: ridge 5px #EEEEEE;
border-radius: 10px;
```

In IE the top of the ridge breaks in the upper right and lower left corners.

[image: ie broken border]

It looks fine in Firefox.  Safari shows a similar break.  How do I fix or work around this?

Comment: Please mention IE version

Comment: IE Version 10. On closer inspection, Firefox is similar, but it looks worse in IE because the contrast is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this before. What I ended up doing was a faux ridge. It requires more markup but it *does* work. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mt2yA/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ridge-outer">
    <div class="ridge-inner">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ridge-outer {
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.ridge-inner {
    border: 2px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You could do this without the additional HTML markup if you used the `:before` or `:after` CSS selectors.